# Scale an SVG to desired size

Tags: svg

I am totally lost when it comes to SVG : I am trying to resize this SVG to be 24 px and be used as an HTML element. 
At the moment, the square is so little it only occupies a pixel ...

Could you show me how to do it please ? Thank you.

Here is the SVG file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="640px" height="480px" viewBox="0 0 640 480" enable-background="new 0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="Calque_1">
  </g>
  <g id="Calque_2">
    <path fill="#AD9D91" d="M348,268h-56v-56h56V268z M293,267h54v-54h-54V267z M334,226h-28v28h28V226z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your example does not occupy a single pixel. You need to provide us with something that actually demnstrates your issue if you wish us to help you.

Comment: Maybe I poolry expressed myself @robert-longson. My example occupies a single pixel when I want to use it as an angular material icon which is supposed to be a 24px square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the viewBox match the dimensions of the shape you've drawn. The one you have is far too big. Of course your shape is not square so you'll either get blanks on two edges or it needs to distort if you want it to occupy a square region. Set preserveAspectRatio="none" if you want distortion.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="640px" height="480px" viewBox="292 212 56 56">
  <rect fill="blue" width="640" height="480"/>
  <g id="Calque_1">
  </g>
  <g id="Calque_2">
    <path fill="#AD9D91" d="M348,268h-56v-56h56V268z M293,267h54v-54h-54V267z M334,226h-28v28h28V226z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain me what did you do ? I am not seeing where you "matched the dimensions of the viewBox with the shape"

Comment: The viewBox  in my answer is not the same as the viewBox in the question is it?

Comment: Sorry, I did the math, it appears that the viewBox fills the width and height properties (292 * 2 + 56 = 640). I did understand, thank you !

Comment: I think that's a coincidence.